# Remove and add options in between other option tags?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I am trying to add some option values after option 2, let say I lik to add options

```
<option value="2a">2a</option>
<option value="2b">2b</option>
<option value="2c">2c</option>
```

and I like to remove option 2

```
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
    </script>

    <select  id="selectCity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
```

So it becomes

```
    <select  id="selectCity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2a">2a</option>
    <option value="2b">2b</option>
    <option value="2c">2c</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
```

so I tried

```
$("#selectCity option[value='2']").remove();

newoptions = '<option value="2a">2a</option><option value="2b">2b</option<option value="2c">2c</option>';
$("#selectCity").append(newoptions);
```

but this just appends the option values as last options not before the 3rd

any other jquery built in function I can take a look at???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed that you asked for replacement.  In that case you wouldn't use insertBefore/insertAfter/or append.  You'd just use replaceWith.

```js
var replacement = [
  '<option value="2a">2a</option>',
  '<option value="2b">2b</option>',
  '<option value="2c">2c</option>'
];

$('#selectCity option').filter('[value="2"]').replaceWith(replacement);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectCity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wfjLL9p/).

```
var elemToReplace = $("#selectCity option[value='2']");

newOptions = '<option value="2a">2a</option><option value="2b">2b</option><option value="2c">2c</option>';

$(newOptions).insertBefore(elemToReplace);

elemToReplace.remove();
```